# PHP login script using bind_result in subsequent query mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

I'm trying to build a relatively simple PHP login script to connect to MySQL database running on my home server. I know the connection works as I've gotten some data returned as I would expect. However, I am having trouble getting the full script to work.

Essentially, I'm taking in a username/password from the user, and I first do a lookup to get the `user_id` from the `users` table. I then want to use that `user_id` value to do a comparison from `user_pswd` table (i'm storing usernames and passwords in separate database tables). At one point, I was able to echo the correct `user_id` based on the username input. But I haven't been able to get all the issues worked out, as I'm pretty new to PHP and don't really know where to see errors since I load this onto my server from a remote desktop. Can anyone offer some advice/corrections to my code?

The end result is I want to send the user to another page, but the echo "test" is just to see if I can get this much working. Thanks so much for the help!

```
<?php

ob_start();

$con = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $con->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$users_name = $_POST['user'];
$users_pass = $_POST['pass'];

$user_esc = $con->real_escape_string($users_name);
$pass_esc = $con->real_escape_string($users_pass);

$query1 = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?;";

if ($result1 = $con->prepare($query1)) {

    $result1->bind_param("s",$user_esc);

    $result1->execute();

    $result1->bind_result($userid);

    $result1->fetch();

    $query2 = "SELECT user_pswd_id FROM user_pswd WHERE active = 1 AND user_id = ? AND user_pswd = ?;";

    if ($result2 = $con->prepare($query2)) {

        $result2->bind_param("is",$userid,$pass_esc);

        $result2->execute();

        $result2->bind_result($userpswd);

        $result2->fetch();

        echo "test", $userpswd;

        $result2->free_result();

        $result2->close();

    } else {
        echo "failed password";
    }

    $result1->free_result();

    $result1->close();
}


$con->close();

ob_end_clean();

?>
```

Comment: *But I haven't been able to get all the issues worked out* is not a correct description of your problem, which part of the code is not working? *i'm storing usernames and passwords in separate database tables*, why are you creating two tables here? <username, password> is not one-to-many, many-to-one or many-to-many relation, it's a one-to-one relation. So just create one table with two columns, one for username and one for the password. Also, assuming the fact that usernames are unique, make this field the primary key of your table.

Comment: i want to be able to store old passwords, so when a user changes their password i will set the old password record to active = 0, and the new password record to active = 1 (active is another field in my user_pswd table). in this way, passwords might be 1 to many. i agree that your suggestion would make it simpler, but i should be able to get it to work with my approach as well (i would think).

Comment: and to your first question, nothing is returned by my echo statement. the echo inside the second if should return "test" + the user_pswd_id field. however, nothing is getting returned by my echo. not even the else echo statement is getting called.

Comment: 1. Turn on error reporting, add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP scripts and see it yields any error or not. 2. Check the status of second prepared statement, do `var_dump($result2);` and see whether the prepared statement has executed successfully or not.